# How to make is_notification false in odoo email by default?

Tags: odoo

I am creating a message using `message_post` and it's creating a mail, but in mail is_notification is `True`.

For all my Users we kept `Never receive notification` as message. So, mails are not creating for them. How can I make `is_notification` `false` by default, when ever mail got created by message?

Comment: Which object are you use? What is the `is_notification`? You need to change default `message_type`?

Comment: Manually i am calling a function message_post from sale_order object. 
self.message_post(cr, SUPERUSER_ID, [resid], type='email', subtype=False, context=context, **post_values)

Comment: Method `message_post` is not have argument `is_notification`. Maybe you want to change default value for [message_type](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/9.0/addons/mail/models/mail_thread.py#L1602)? Object **sale.order** uses method `message_post` of **mail.thread**. You can check [sale.order](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/9.0/addons/sale/sale.py#L17) to ensure that the method is not overridden.

Comment: ok thank you RobAu, i will try it